# Access debug log messages

Tags: debugging, logging

I can query debug logs via `ApexLog` object with SOQL, but the result doesn't contain an actual message.

How can I access the message? Is it achievable with SOQL or some API?

Comment: Explore tooling API for same .I need to do some homework to get to actual answer but thats hint to start

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tooling API has support since v 28 to download the Raw Apex Log. See [this](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_tooling/Content/sforce_api_objects_apexlog.htm) for more info.

Comment: Is it possible to get the Raw Apex Log with partner SOAP API?

Comment: No, you cannot get the debug log using Partner API or any other Salesforce provided API

Answer (score 0):

It is possible also with REST Api, using the following path:

```
"/services/data/v29.0/sobjects/ApexLog/" + logId + "/Body/"
```

The log Id must be known (could be fetched with simple SOQL) and only one log per request can be fetched.